# Two separate hosted e-mail services for one domain, can't send mail between them

Tags: email, g-suite

My client registered an email address on Google as `webmaster@example.com` using the Google API. Later he registered the domain `example.com` at MochaHost.

I have then created another email address `support@example.com` over the hosting space (not on google) using control panel.

I am then using `support@example.com` to send emails to his customers. The emails are successfully sent to all customers.

The issue here is that the client wants a notification email to be sent to his email address `webmaster@example.com` also (while it is on google). When I try to send email to this address, it bounces with a "mailbox not available" error message.

As far my understanding goes, I think this is happening as the domain name is same in `webmaster@example.com` and `support@example.com`, so considering the same domain it tries to send the mail over the same domain whereas webmaster does not exist in that case.

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:asp.net], [tag:iis7.5] and [tag:c#] ?

Comment: because i have tested with Asp.net C# code.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425015/emailing-sending-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the MX record for `example.com` pointing to Google Apps or the MochaHost server?

If your client would prefer all `example.com` e-mail to be handled by Google Apps, the MX records for `example.com` need to be configured according to Google's instructions (e.g. `aspmx.l.google.com`). In that case, you would no longer be able to receive mail at MochaHost.

If your client would prefer all `example.com` e-mail to be handled by MochaHost, leave the MX records for `example.com` alone and create a `webmaster@example.com` account on the MochaHost server.

I would recommend that you create a `support@example.com` mailbox on Google Apps, then configure the MX records per Google's instructions so that all of `example.com`'s messages are handled by Google. Web hosting companies' e-mail services are not as robust as dedicated offerings like Google Apps and Office 365.

If you are trying to send mail from the web server, it needs to be configured to relay the messages externally. Currently, your web server is trying to send mail to itself.

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer solves your problem, you can accept it by clicking the check mark to the left.

Answer (score -1):

Try configuring the account support@somedomain.com on google, and using google's SMTP to send the mail

Reason being: Google checks all their incoming mail has a domain that matches to avoid spoof emails from spam scripts

Comment: How is he going to receive mail via Google Apps if the MX record is pointing somewhere else?

Comment: I'm sure the MX record is pointing to Google Apps because otherwise his client would be freaking out about not getting e-mail. He's using the webhost SMTP to send mail with a script, which doesn't require incoming MX to work.